# Actualizar datatable cuando cambia un <p:inputText>

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, primefaces, java-ee

Buen dia estoy intentando hacer un sistema de prestamos en el cual al digitar un numero de identificación dentro de un **p:InputText** por medio de ajax realiza una busqueda en la base de datos y me obtiene un cliente [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] la idea es que cuando yo busque a este cliente me devuelva una lista de prestamos que se le han realizado y los muestre en una **p:dataTable**, lo que tengo hasta hecho y no se porque no funciona es lo siguiente:

```
   <h:form id="formPrincipal">
                    <p:growl life="5000" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
                    <p:panel header="PRESTAMOS" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; width: 1000px;
                             margin: 0 auto;">
                        <p:layout id="idDatosCliente" style="width: 100%; height: 185px">

                            <p:layoutUnit position="center" style="padding: 5px; text-align: center; 
                                          font-size: 14px;" size="300">

                                <p:inputText placeholder="Buscar clientes - ingresa aquí el número de cedula"
                                         size="100" value="#{prestamoBean.cedula}">
                                <p:ajax listener="#{prestamoBean.buscarCliente()}" event="keyup"
                                        update=":formPrincipal:gridCliente :formPrincipal:tblPrestamo"/>
                            </p:inputText>
                                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="PF('dialogCrear').show();"
                                                 update=":formCrear:dlgCrear"/>

                                <p:separator/>

                                <p:panelGrid columns="4" id="gridCliente"
                                             style="width: 100%; text-align: justify;">
                                    <h:outputText value="NOMBRE: "/>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{prestamoBean.cliente.nombreCliente}"/>

                                    <h:outputText value="EMPRESA: "/>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{prestamoBean.cliente.empresa.codigoEmpresa}"/>

                                    <h:outputText value="TASA DE INTERES: "/>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{prestamoBean.cliente.tasaInteres} %"/>

                                    <h:outputText value="No. CUENTA: "/>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{prestamoBean.cliente.numeroCuenta}"/>
                                </p:panelGrid>

                                <p:separator/>
                                <div id="cabeceraDiv">
                                    ACCIONES
                                </div>

                                <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
                                    <p:commandButton value="GENERAR PRESTAMO" onclick="PF('dialogNuevoPrestamo').show();"/>
                                    <p:commandButton value="PAGO DE INTERESES"/>
                                    <p:commandButton value="PAGO CAPITAL"/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:layoutUnit>
                        </p:layout>
                        <P></P>
                        <p:dataTable id="tblPrestamo" emptyMessage="NO HAY PRESTAMOS PENDIENTES"
                                     value="#{prestamoBean.listaPrestamo}"
                                     var="r">
                            <p:column headerText="FECHA">
                                <h:outputText value="${r.fecha}"/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="DESCRIPCION">
                                <h:outputText value="${r.concepto}"/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="DEBE">
                                <h:outputText value="${r.debe}"/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="HABER">
                                <h:outputText value="${r.haber}"/>

                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="SALDO">
                                <h:outputText value="${r.saldo}"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>

                    </p:panel>

                </h:form>
```

y este es el Bean que estoy realizando al cual le falta mucho pero voy paso por paso y este para mi es super importante:

```
public List<Prestamo> getListaPrestamo() {
        return listaPrestamo;

    }

    public void setListaPrestamo(List<Prestamo> listaPrestamo) {
        this.listaPrestamo = listaPrestamo;
    }

    //Metodo que devuelve los prestamos
    public void ObtenerPrestamos() {
 this.session = null;
    Integer codigoCliente = this.cliente.getCodigoCliente();
    prestamoDao pDao = new PrestamoDaoImp();
    this.listaPrestamo = pDao.BuscarIDCliente(this.session, codigoCliente);

    }


//Busqueda Instantanea de clientes
    public void buscarCliente() {

        this.session = null;
        this.transaction = null;

        try {

            if (this.cedula == null) {
                return;
            }

            clienteDao cDao = new clienteDaoImp();
            this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            this.transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            this.cliente = cDao.BuscarCedula(this.session, cedula);

            if (this.cliente != null) {
                this.cedula = null;
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Correcto", "Cliente encontrado"));
                ObtenerPrestamos();
            } else {
                this.cedula = null;
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "Cliente no encontrado"));

            }

            this.transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (this.transaction != null) {
                this.transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if (this.session != null) {
                this.session.close();
            }
        }

    }

    //BUsqueda normal de clientes por medio de botón recibiendo parametro cedula
    public void buscarCliente2(String cedula) {

        this.session = null;
        this.transaction = null;

        try {

            if (this.cedula == null) {
                return;
            }

            clienteDao cDao = new clienteDaoImp();
            this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            this.transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            this.cliente = cDao.BuscarCedula(this.session, cedula);

            if (this.cliente != null) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Correcto", "Cliente encontrado"));
                ObtenerPrestamos();
            } else {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "Cliente no encontrado"));

            }

            this.transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (this.transaction != null) {
                this.transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if (this.session != null) {
                this.session.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

El metodo

> ObtenerPrestamos()

es el que busca por medio del codigo del cliente la lista de prestamos para llenar la variable

> listaPrestamo

Ademas de esto public tambien el metodo que uso para buscar el codigoCliente en la base de datos y que retorna una lista, haber si allí es donde tengo el problema y no me he dado cuenta.

```
public List<Prestamo> BuscarIDCliente(Session session,Integer codigoCliente) {

        List<Prestamo> lista = null;
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "FROM Prestamo WHERE codigoCliente = :codigoCliente";

        try {

            lista = session.createQuery(hql).list();
            t.commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            t.rollback();
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

He actualizado la pregunta agregando esta vez el como hago para llenar la lista, depronto estoy haciendo algo mal. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve estudiando bien el codigo en especial el que me generaba la lista despues de la respuesta a la base de datos y lo pude modificar de la siguiente manera

public List OtroBuscar(Session session, Integer codigoCliente) {
        String hql = "FROM Prestamo WHERE codigoCliente = :codigoCliente";
        Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
        q.setParameter("codigoCliente", codigoCliente);

```
    return q.list();
}
```

luego lo que hice fue que en vez de usar el metodo **ObtenerPrestamos()** lo que hice fue incluir 
this.listaPrestamo = pDao.OtroBuscar(this.session, this.cliente.getCodigoCliente()); 
dentro del metodo que me busca el cliente y a la vez se llena la lista. debajo publico como me quedó el codigo con la modificacion.

public void buscarCliente() {

```
    this.session = null;
    this.transaction = null;

    try {

        if (this.cedula == null) {
            return;
        }

        clienteDao cDao = new clienteDaoImp();
        prestamoDao pDao = new PrestamoDaoImp();
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        this.transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        this.cliente = cDao.BuscarCedula(this.session, cedula);


        if (this.cliente != null) {
            this.cedula = null;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Correcto", "Cliente encontrado"));
            this.listaPrestamo = pDao.OtroBuscar(this.session, this.cliente.getCodigoCliente()); 
        } else {
            this.cedula = null;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "Cliente no encontrado"));

        }

        this.transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (this.transaction != null) {
            this.transaction.rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        if (this.session != null) {
            this.session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

La búsqueda se hace a partir de este inputText, con un evento keyup:

```
<p:inputText placeholder="Buscar clientes - ingresa aquí el número de cedula"
                                             size="100" value="#{prestamoBean.cedula}">
                                    <p:ajax listener="#{prestamoBean.buscarCliente()}" event="keyup" 
                                            update=":formPrincipal:gridCliente"/>
                                </p:inputText>
```

Una vez finaliza se actualiza el componente `:formPrincipal:gridCliente`

Tu tabla está fuera de ese componente, con lo que no se actualiza.

Comment: Cuidado. Por temas de performance, convendría limitar la ejecución del `keyup` para que funcione luego de 3 o más caracteres para evitar hacer búsquedas innecesarias.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, la búsqueda debería lanzarse al pulsar el botón que existe justo debajo del anterior.

Comment: O podría hacerse en el `onblur` que es cuando se pierde el foco del componente.

Comment: También, la cosa es que no veo utilidad al otro botón.

Comment: Mi gente gracias por sus comentarios, pero ya hice incluí en el update de p:ajax el id de la tabla de los clientes, pero aun así no pasa nada, agradezco me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con el código tal y como lo tienes ahora.

Comment: En el update del p:ajax tienes puestos dos componentes diferentes pero falta una coma entre ellos, separando los dos identificadores.

Comment: la parte del codigo donde aparece el metido  **public List<Prestamo> BuscarIDCliente(Session session,Integer codigoCliente) { ** si está bien @pablo

Comment: lo intenté como me dijiste @pablo y no me está funcionando, realmente no se me ocurre que está pasando y el porque no funciona, o si hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo seria genial

Comment: Prueba poniendo update="gridCliente,tblPrestamo"

Comment: @pablo ya estoy creyendo que el problema no está allí en el update sino en la lista resultante de la consulta que le hago a la base de datos, podrias revisarla por favor?

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer debug en esa parte y ver si el método ObtenerPrestamos devuelve resultados?